# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule not working

Tags: wordpress

I have the page `my-page`, which has page id `38` .

I want to turn

`http://www.example.com/my-page?q=page-title`

to

`http://www.example.com/my-page/page-title`

I've tried adding this rewrite rule to functions.php.  I keep getting page not found.

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%my-page%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);


function custom_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^my-page/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=38&q=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) function.

> This function is useful when used with custom post types as it allows for automatic flushing of the WordPress rewrite rules (usually needs to be done manually for new custom post types). However, this is an expensive operation so it should only be used when absolutely necessary